# PHP Call to undefined function How to resolve error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function Sale_bill($id){
    $data['Sales'] = $this->Sales_model->get_sales_by_id($id);
    $data['Sold_items'] = $this->Sales_model->sold_items_by_sale_id($id);
    $GST_Percentages = array(0, 2.5, 6, 9, 14);
    foreach($GST_Percentages as $GST_Percentage){
        $data['GST_data'][] = array($GST_Percentage => '');
        $data['GST_data'][$i][$GST_Percentage] = array_filter($data['Sold_items'], sold_item_by_gst_percentage($data['Sold_items'], $GST_Percentage));
    }
}
private function sold_item_by_gst_percentage($GST, $GST_Percentage){
    return ($GST['CGST_Percentage'] == $GST_Percentage);
}
```

When I am calling sold_item_by_gst_percentage it saying `Call to undefined function sold_item_by_gst_percentage()` How can I resolve this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
$this->sold_item_by_gst_percentage($data['Sold_items'], $GST_Percentage)
```

Comment: It doesn't depend on the CI version. And it's called "CodeIgniter", not "codeigntor".